# How to pick top 100 from each groups within a column?

Tags: python, pandas

pick top N values from each group in a dataframe column

[image: dataframe needed]

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise the `rank` function to get an ordered row number for each group and only take the first 2 rows for each group to get the wanted dataframe.

In code:

```
df1['rn'] = df1.groupby('year')['rank'].rank(ascending=False)
result_df = df1[df1['rn'] <= 2].drop('rn', axis=1)
```

Which gives the wanted result:

```
   year  rank   name
0  1999     5    ria
1  1999     3    kay
3  2000     4    ria
4  2000     2  manny
```

Modifying the number 2 to any wanted `N` will give the top `N` rows from each group.

Comment: why add the rank to the dataframe just to drop it again?  seems easier to keep it seperate and only use it for indexing

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the reply but I need to first group my data frame by year and then sort the book value of the company within each year.  And then I need to pick top 20 companies for each year according to their book values

Comment: @SamMason Correct, I'm creating the rank in case the OP wants to experiment with it and check what it is doing and dropping it to get the exact same output as expected by the OP. @Karishma That is exactly what this code is doing, group by year, sort by rank column by descending order, give it a row number in that order and take only first 2 rows in each group. You can check the `df1['rn']` column to confirm.

Comment: Got it. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby `year` and take the first two rows in each group with `head(2)`:

```
df1.groupby('year').head(2)

#    year  rank   name                                      
# 0  1999     5    ria                                        
# 1  1999     3    kay                                        
# 3  2000     4    ria                                        
# 4  2000     2  manny
```

---

Note that for unsorted data you might need to sort before grouping, e.g.

```
df1.sort_values(['year', 'rank'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('year').head(2)
```

Comment: OP might need `sort_values` as this assumes the data is already in the correct order (i.e. highest rank first)

Comment: Correct, @SamMason - example data looked already sorted, but you're right.